# Proving $k\binom{n}{k} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, combinations

Prove that
$$k\binom{n}{k} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$ is true for all integers $n, k$ with $0 \leq  k \leq  n$.

Would this be enough to prove this?

$$\binom nk=\frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}=n\cdot\frac{(n-1)!}{k\cdot (k-1)!\cdot [(n-1)-(k-1)]!}$$

$$\implies \binom nk=\frac nk \binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

Comment: Do you mean $k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}?$

Comment: I think it should be $0 < k \le n$.

Comment: Hi, yes, I fixed question to reflect this.

Comment: @Wilson You also need to fix $k>0.$ It is ok.

Answer (score 2):

One also has the combinatorial proof. The number $k\displaystyle \binom nk$ counts the ways of picking a $k$ subset of $n$, and then a distinguished element of it. That is, a pair $(\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\},a_i)$. But if we pick first a distinguished element from $n$; and then a $k-1$ subset of $n-1$, we're choosing the same thing, this time in $n\displaystyle \binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways, i.e. a pair $(j,\{a_1,\ldots,a_{k-1}\})$, so these numbers coincide.

Answer (score 1):

Writing as a string of equalities might be cleaner:
$$
k\binom{n}{k} = k \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = n\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}
$$
This is true for $k = 0$ if you follow the convention that $\binom{n}{k} = 0$ for nonpositive values of $k$.

Answer (score 0):

If you supply the missing factor of $n$ on the right of what you are trying to prove and do not allow $k=0$, it is fine.

Comment: Hi, K can = 0 according to the question - what would I have to change to account for this?

Comment: If you define ${n \choose -1}=0$, then it is OK.  Otherwise, not.  What is your definition?  If so, you need to adapt your proof not to divide by $k$ in that case.

Comment: I'm not really sure to be honest! These are just questions im given, with no other information.

Comment: @Wilson Then it was probably overlooked by whoever wrote the question.